# The conditioning is not taken into account in a If statment with excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

the 2 last conditions are not taken into account when the below code is exceuted. Can you help to understand why?
Also the "r" range retreive me the expected results + 1 row. I did not manage to change this. Any ideas?

```
Dim x As Range
Dim r As Range
Dim j As Range

 Set r = Range("J2").End(xlDown)
 Set j = Range("D2").End(xlDown)
    For Each x In Range("J2", r)
     If x.Value < 0 And j = ("long") Or j = ("") Then
     x.Offset(1, 0).Select
     ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+RC[-1]"
   End If
  Next
 End Sub
```

Comment: could you be more specific on what the problem is? and I don't think you can set a range like that(not sure though).

Comment: The problem is only the 1st condition is working "if x.Value < 0", "j = ("long") Or j = ("")" are not taken into account. I also tried "j.value", J.cells" but it did worked either.

Comment: maybe `if (x.Value < 0) And (j = ("long") Or j = (""))`? or some other combination whaterver youre trying to achieve with that statement. Keep in mind execution order of operators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI: r range in your code will be the last used cell of column J starting from J2. There should be no empty cell in between.

try this:

```
Sub posted()
Dim x As Range
Dim r As Range
'Dim j As Range

Set r = Range("J2").End(xlDown)
'Set j = Range("D2").End(xlDown)

For Each x In Range("J2", r)

If (x.Value < 0) And ((x.Offset(, -6).value = "long") _
Or (x.Offset(, -6).value = "")) Then

'''''''''dont know if you want cell value by long or number format of the cell''''
'If (x.Value < 0) And ((x.Offset(, -6).NumberFormat = "Number") _
Or (x.Offset(, -6) = "")) Then
'''''''''

x.Offset(1, 0).Select    
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+RC[-1]"
End If
Next
Set r = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: That's perfectly what I was looking for (I wanted cell value by long). Many thanks for your help.